# Update customfield in JIRA::Client in Perl

Tags: perl, jira

I would like to create new issue with `JIRA::Client` in Perl; but it throws an exception as
"soapenv:Server.userException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at D:\
ji.pl line 20"

```
use JIRA::Client;
use SOAP::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32;

$adminuser = $ENV{USERNAME};
$adminpwd  = $ARGV[0];

eval { $jira = JIRA::Client->new('http://jira.com/',$adminuser,$adminpwd) }
  or die "Invalid Credentials";

my $newissue = $jira->create_issue(
  {
    project => 'VVSPL29',
    summary => 'UTP_ARR',
    type    => 'Work Product',
    customFieldValues =>  [
      {
       'customfieldId' => 'customfield_11380',
       'values'=>[SOAP::Data->type('string','747-8')]
      },
      {
       'customfieldId' => 'customfield_10727',
       'values' =>[SOAP::Data->type('string','UIL_EDS')]
      },
      {
       'customfieldId' => 'customfield_11086',
       'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string','8')]
      },
      {
       'customfieldId' => 'customfield_10200',
       'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string',"5/Nov/13")]
      },
      {
       'customfieldId' => 'customfield_11572',
       'values' => [SOAP::Data->type('string','Init Dev')]
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

Please help me figure out where I go wrong.

Comment: Which line is number 20?

Comment: Line No:20  my $newissue = $jira->create_issue(